# How to handle augmentations that change the label in image classification?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a simple network using Tensorflow to classify faces into 3 classes.

- Face looking to the **left**
- Face looking to the **right**
- Face looking to the **center**

I want to apply image augmentation to my dataset, in particular `horizontal_flip` but I can't use it because I would need to change the label if this transformation is applied to a face looking **left** or **right**.

What could be the best way to apply this "label changing" transformations?

Answer (score 1):

tricky problem but doable. Best way is to use dataframes. I will assume you have a directory called faces. It has 3 sub directories left (for looking left images), right (for looking right images) and center (for looking straight ahead image)
First thing to do is to create a dataframe to hold the paths to the images and their associated labels.

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2
sdir=r'c:\temp\faces'
sdir=r'C:\Temp\left right'
classlist=os.listdir(sdir) 
filepaths=[]
labels=[]    
for klass in classlist:
    classpath=os.path.join(sdir,klass)        
    flist=os.listdir(classpath)    
    for f in flist:
        fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)        
        filepaths.append(fpath)
        labels.append(klass) 
Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')    
df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)     
print('df length: ', len(df))
```

now we have a data frame. Next create a set of directories to hold our augmented images

```
working_dir=sdir
aug_dir=os.path.join(working_dir, 'aug')
if os.path.isdir(aug_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(aug_dir)
os.mkdir(aug_dir)
for label in df['labels'].unique():
    dir_path=os.path.join(aug_dir,label)    
    os.mkdir(dir_path)
```

now we have a sub directory aug in the faces directory. The aug directory has 3 sub directories left, right, center to store the augmented images. Next create the horizontally flipped images and store them in the proper sub directory of the aug directory

```
groups=df.groupby('labels') # group by class
for label in df['labels'].unique():  # for every class               
    group=groups.get_group(label)  # a dataframe holding only rows with the specified label     
    for i in range(len(group)):
        fpath=group['filepaths'].iloc[i]
        img=cv2.imread(fpath) # read in the file
        img=cv2.flip(img, 1)  # horizontally flip it
        fname=os.path.split(fpath)[1] # get the name of the file 
        if label=='center': # if processing center label images store in aug/center
            destpath=os.path.join(aug_dir, 'center', fname)           
        elif label== 'left': if processing left label images store in aug/right
            destpath=os.path.join(aug_dir, 'right', fname)            
        else: # if processing right labeled images store the result in aug/left
            destpath=os.path.join(aug_dir, 'left', fname )
            
        cv2.imwrite(destpath, img ) # write the flipped image to the destination
```

now we have the augmented images stored we need to combine then with the original images

```
aug_fpaths=[]
aug_labels=[]
classlist=os.listdir(aug_dir)
for klass in classlist:
    classpath=os.path.join(aug_dir, klass)     
    flist=os.listdir(classpath)
    print (len(flist))
    for f in flist:        
        fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)         
        aug_fpaths.append(fpath)
        aug_labels.append(klass)
Fseries=pd.Series(aug_fpaths, name='filepaths')
Lseries=pd.Series(aug_labels, name='labels')
aug_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
ndf=pd.concat([df,aug_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

dataframe ndf now contains the original images plus the augmented images. From there
you can split ndf into train_df, test_df and validation_df. Then create train, test and validation generators using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe